# html, css Вписать любое изображение в окне по ширине и высоте с пропорциями. Изображения имеют разные соотношения сторон

Tags: javascript, html, css

Надо вписать изображение в окно сохраняя пропорции. Фотография может быть разных размеров 1000х200 или 333х1280. В основном есть информация как вписать по ширине, но если попадается "высокая" фотография тогда она увеличивается в размере до своего максимума или до ширины.

Надо вписать 100% любое изображение в окно.

Эффект должен быть такой, как если на компе открыть с помощью браузера фотографию.

Comment: [object-fit: contain;](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) для img

Answer (score 1):

Вашу проблему можно легко решить, если использовать данное свойство со значением: **contain** или **scale-down**. Эти значения мало чем различаются, но попробовать и посмотреть что лучше, все таки стоит. Свойство следует применять напрямую к img или video.

`object-fit: contain;`

или

`object-fit: scale-down`

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот таким способом. [пример](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/object-fit+image+cover+to+size+stretch)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}
</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <img src="1.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```